# How to give virtualbox more GPU memory?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, ram, gpu

I have a NVIDIA GTX 960 graphics card with 2 GB of memory.

The problem I encounter is in `virtualbox` I can only give up to 128 MB of video memory. I need much more, so how do I configure `virtualbox` to give a virtual machine 1.5 GB of video memory?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: VB uses an emulated video driver, and I don't know of any way to give it more than 128M of memory. What are you doing in VB that requires that much GPU memory? If it's a heavy duty game, you should probably dual-boot if it's a Windows game.

Comment: With guest additions you will make full use of the host GPU VRAM for 3D rendering.

Comment: @heynnema i'm using hash crackers that need a ton of GPU

Comment: @Takkat can you post a link  to a setup tutorial please? thanks

Comment: @tomsharon you can't use the host GPU for hash cracking software running in a VM.